# VB.Net Not populating array with db data

Tags: mysql, arrays, vb.net, function, object

I want to fill up an array with data from mysql database

here is my code

```
Dim DataBlob As String()
        Dim Count As Integer

        While READER.Read
            Count += 1
            Dim eName As String = READER(1)
            Dim eSname As String = READER(2)
            Dim eID As String = READER(0)

            DataBlob(Count) = eSname + eName

        End While

        Return DataBlob
```

But i dont see anything being returned. What might be the problem

Note: There is a warning stating : `DataBlob is used before a value is assigned`

Comment: Arrays don't magically grow like that.  You haven't even actually created an array there at all but, even if you had, you can't just specify any index you want.  The array has to have enough elements for that index to be valid.  If you want something like an array that can grow dynamically then use a `List(Of T)` where `T` is the type of the items you want to store in it.  In your case, `T` would be `String`.  You can then call the `Add` method to add an item to the list.  This is pretty basic stuff that most beginners tutorials will take you through, so I suggest that you work through one.

Comment: Ok can u help me out. I just want to fill up an array dynamically with data from the db

Comment: I already did help you. I told you to use a generic `List`.  You can use that in basically the same way as you do an array afterwards, i.e. get and set by index.  If you really must have an array though, you can call `ToArray` on the `List` to get one.  You can't really start out with an array because they cannot be resized and you don't know how many elements you need ahead of time. You can use `ReDim` or `Array.Resize` if you really must but they should generally be avoided. The `List(Of T)` exists to behave as a dynamic array so you should use it when that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array, just get the count 1st

```
Dim Count as integer=reader_count(0)  
Dim DataBlob(count-1) As String
'subtract 1 b/c array starts at zero
Dim i as integer=0
While READER.Read
        Dim eName As String = READER(1)
        Dim eSname As String = READER(2)
        Dim eID As String = READER(0)
        DataBlob(i) = eSname + eName
        i+=1
End While
```

One other option, if you know your count is limited (let's say your always pulling the Countries of the World in your reader, you could just overestimate), then when you are done, you redim the array, but you must use preserve.  I would not do this unless you were dealing with small arrays.

```
'there is no way the reader will return more than 500
Dim DataBlob(500) As String
While READER.Read
        Count += 1
        Dim eName As String = READER(1)
        Dim eSname As String = READER(2)
        Dim eID As String = READER(0)
        DataBlob(Count) = eSname + eName
End While
ReDim Preserve DataBlob(Count)
```